# Is it possible to integrate OSGi with Spring Data?

Tags: spring, osgi, spring-data

I'm currently working on an OSGi application running under apache Karaf that uses JPA and QueryDSL.

I was wondering if I could use Spring Data with QueryDSL instead of the current approach.

The reason for this is that I find Spring repositories to be quite useful and having a template for NoSQL database accesses might be useful in the future.

I have tried to start a normal spring application without a web context with OSGi but I get a ClassNoutFoundException when it tries to load the applicationContext.xml or the ApplicationContext.class.

I don't want to use Spring DM since it is discontinued.

Basically the sole reason for wanting to try this integration is for the Spring Repositories, but if you think this is not necessary please tell me. Any information regarding how to achive this or if it's ok to persue this would be more than welcome.

Thank you

**Update**

I've managed to make spring work by starting the application context with `org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext`. The applicationContext is exported in OSGi as a service and I can get all the beans that I need by calling it.

The problem I'm having right now is that when I declare `<jpa:repositories base-package="x.y.z" />` I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in URL [bundle://251.13:0/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence exception translators found in bean factory. Cannot perform exception translation.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)[185:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)[185:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)[185:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)[185:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)[185:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)[185:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109)[187:org.springframework.context:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:502)[193:org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.core:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:451)[193:org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.core:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:306)[193:org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.core:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)[193:org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.core:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:290)[193:org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.core:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:137)[194:org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender:1.0.0.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)[:1.6.0_37]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence exception translators found in bean factory. Cannot perform exception translation.
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:142)[195:org.springframework.transaction:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)[195:org.springframework.transaction:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)[195:org.springframework.transaction:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:103)[195:org.springframework.transaction:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)[185:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1443)[185:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)[185:org.springframework.beans:3.1.4.RELEASE]
```

As a JPA provider I'm using OpenJPA. The entityManagerFactory is a service which I can get by using the blueprint. I think I need to reference it in `<jpa:repositories base-package="x.y.z" />`, but how do I do that since the applicationContext.xml is read by spring and not the blueprint?

I would really appreciate any hint in the right direction.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Use Querydsl-SQL directly in your code and

- it will work well within OSGi as it does not use class loading, weaving, enhancing, caching and other tricks that sound really good but causes chaos
- your code will run much faster than with any of the "cache-enhanced" JPA engines
- others will be able to understand your code (not like JPA Criteria API queries)
- you will know exactly what SQL commands run on the Database Server that minimizes problem-solving time
- your code will be as database independent as with any ORM tool

Do not use Spring, spring-data, JPA and other monoholitic technologies together with OSGi as

- they were designed to work within monoholitic systems where everything is in one application context, not in separate bundles
- by using these technologies together with OSGi you will spend most of your time to fix bugs like this and looking for workarounds

People who argue with this, already spent lots of time on finding such workarounds. They managed to implement some business logic. They hope that they now truly found workarounds for every conceptual issue and they do not have to spend the same amount of work next time. They are in a [bidding fee auction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidding_fee_auction). Be honest guys! Somewhere deep you know I am right ;-).

I am saying this with the experience that I

- tried the perfect stack based on Hibernate and [Don't repeat the DAO](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-genericdao/) article of IBM (much before Spring-Data hype began). Twice
- wrote [hibernate-osgi-adapter](https://github.com/everit-org-archive/osgi-hibernate) for Hibernate 4.1.x
- [Re-implemented](https://github.com/everit-org-archive/osgi-jpa-container) the complete JPA chapter of OSGi Enterprise specification

Comment: P.s.: I did not write this answer for bounty. I wrote this to put the bug into the ears of developers who have use perfect ORM based stack that integrates every layer, yet they spend 50% of their time looking for workarounds.

Comment: This don't really answer to my question. I'm still not really convinced, even if I know deeply :), that you're probably right ;). But this is clear enough to allow me to award you the bounty.

Answer (score 4):

Well you have a couple of choices here, try to get it to run with blueprint (probably the hardest - since you need to call spring beans, but I think could still be done), use Karaf 3.0.0.RC1 it also supports Blueprint Geminin which does have a tighter support for Spring and last but not least use Spring-DM, even if it is discontinued you are able to use and probable the best approach is to use spring-dm for certain Spring specific parts and std. Blueprint for the rest. Because you just use services through both frameworks everything will work, just don't mix the spring and blueprint descriptors in one bundle.

Comment: Spring DM is not discontinued. It was renamed to "Gemini Blueprint".

Comment: But now it's blueprint which is slightly different then the spring-dm syntax, so one might call it "discontinued". I still use it for certain scenarios ... :)

Comment: Thanks Achim Nierbeck. Because of your answer I found that Spring DM class that made Spring work. I've also updated my answer. If you know anything about integrating Apache Karaf with Spring Data I would really appreciate it. Thanks again :)

Comment: Marius, sorry never used spring data, for all jpa stuff I usually use Aries JPA.